# How do I resolve this "transfer agent" issue?

Tags: liveagent

This is more of a question on Salesforce functionality rather than a development question.

Right now, I want to learn about transferring from one agent to another.  I have two Users on my system, both are marked as Live Agent User in the Setup page for Users.  I initiate a chat from a chat link on my page, and a chat begins with one of the users (which is the System Administrator).  In another browser I'm logged in as the other user.  I try to "transfer" the visitor to the second user, but I get a message like this:

"Can't transfer chat "00000194" because no agents are available."

How can I make my other user available?

Here's another thing: when I log in with the other user, it seems that only Salesforce Classic is displayed, and not Lightning.

I have tried a few things, but nothing makes a ton of sense.  I tried using some steps here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service_basics/service_basics_configure_console but I can't seem to enable a "Sample Console" for my second user.

I'm using a free trial; I'm interested in checking out the "transfer agents" functionality, as our customer will be using this feature.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to grant lightning permission to the second user via You have to add them to the Permission Set that grants "Lightning Experience Users"
2. The transfer is only possible when another user is online within the same queue, so you need to add both users under the same queue
3. Check on OmniSupervisor console or on live agent console how many users are online, are they on the same queue, if not add another user to a button's queue from where chat is initiated

Comment: Well, it does not seem that I can assign "Lightning Experience Users" to my second user.  I don't see "Lightning Experience Users" in the Permission Sets.  In Permission Sets, I have CRM User, Live Agent Setup Flow, Sales Cloud User, Salesforce Console User, Service Cloud User, and Standard Einstein Activity Console.  Any idea how I can get "Lightning Experience User"?  I have a feeling I need to call Salesforce.

Comment: Lightning Experience User is available under 'Salesforce'  license. I checked for CRM User this permission is not available, yes please check with salesforce what to do in case of CRM User.